# How to access ng-repeat expression in another html file to make a single html page for different array values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to angular JS
Here is the main html page, I want to pass {{Product.detail}} on ng-click to another detail.html, There will be a single detail.html but on different {{Product.Names}} click it will change detail as per the {{Product.Names}}, andy easy way to do that.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="LoginHome">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Shop</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HomeStyle.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="HomeScript.js"></script>

        <body>
            <div>
                <div ng-controller="HomeController">
                    <h1>Products</h1>
                    <div class="product-card" ng-repeat="Product in Products">
                        <div class="image-card" >
                            <div class="imagepadding">
                                <img  class="responsiveImage"ng-src="{{Product.images}}"></img>
                            </div>
                            <div class="Title-Price">
                                <label class="text-Font" ng-click="goToDetail(Product.detail)">
                                    {{Product.Names}}

                                </label>
                                <label class="text-Font">
                                    {{Product.Price}}

                                </label>
                                <button class="buyBtn">Add to Cart</button>
                            </div>                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Below is the javascript file with controller

```
    var app=angular.module('LoginHome',['ngRoute']);
    app.controller('HomeController',['$scope','$window',function($scope, $window){

    $scope.Products=[
    {images: 'D:/angular/shop/src/home/robot3.jpg',Names: "ASIMO ", Price: "$1000",detail: "hello" },
    {images:"D:/angular/shop/src/home/robot2.jfif",Names: "Bionic Hand", Price: "$2000",detail: "hi"},
    {images:"D:/angular/shop/src/home/robot4.jpg",Names: "Turtle Bot", Price: "$3000",detail: "heyyy"}];


    $scope.goToDetail=
                function(){

                $window.location="D:/angular/shop/src/home/details.html";//Here i want to pass {{Product.detail}} to detail.html on particular ng-click to show only the detail of only that array object


            }
        }]);
```

Comment: Are you using an angularjs router? Because setting $window.location is not really the way to go.

Comment: No for view I was using it but that didn't work out

Comment: "Didn't work out" how? You definitely don't want to be doing full page refreshes of an angularjs app. It totally defeats the purpose of using angular in the first place.

Comment: path was having some problem like where(/homepage)..It was showing me page not  found  wasn't able to figure out that's why using window.location

Comment: I'd suggest that's the issue you need to solve. Yes, as per the given answer you could set a URL parameter with the product id. But reloading the page means reloading all of the app, and angularjs apps are not lightweight. This is what ui router is designed for.

Comment: yeah need to learn about it any recommended tutorial for angularjs router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to have the detail page setup so it takes a product id as url parameter.
Seems like you are missing a product id altogether, I would recommend as best practice to have one.

Then the detail page can take this url parameter, make an api call to get the details of this product, like the image, name, price, etc. and display them for that product.

It is the same detail page, and works for any product. Then in the list view that you have built now, you just link `a href` to the right details page with the product id passed in as url parameter.

**UPDATED**

To start off let's add the product id to the product definition.

```
products= [
    {id: '1', images: 'D:/angular/shop/src/home/robot3.jpg',Names: "ASIMO ", Price: "$1000",detail: "hello" },
    {id: '2', images:"D:/angular/shop/src/home/robot2.jfif",Names: "Bionic Hand", Price: "$2000",detail: "hi"},
    {id: '3', images:"D:/angular/shop/src/home/robot4.jpg",Names: "Turtle Bot", Price: "$3000",detail: "heyyy"}];
```

Also, let's put this definition somewhere else, like in a Service. (See [This tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/6685/angularjs-services-example-tutorial#creating-and-registering-angular-services) on how to create a service) This Service, should be named let's call it APIService. And a method in this service named getProducts() to return this array. Another method named getProductDetailsById(id) to return one row from this array, where the id matches the product id.
Going forward these products will need to be saved in a database and returned via some APIs, so this service will help at that step.

Now let's make a new html page, and add a new controller to it. Call it details page and detailsController. This controller needs the `$routeParams` injected so then we can get `$routeParams.productId`. For the route params to work please follow [this tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/6225/angularjs-routing-example-ngroute-routeprovider) on how to get it setup for this url and other within the application.
Once we have the `productId` from the `$routeParams`, then we can call that APIService (needs to be injected) like: `APIService.getProductDetails($routeParams.productId)` and this will return the product details (one of the items in the array as we defined above).

With this then we can populate the things we want in `$scope` to be displayed on the rendered page.

Comment: If you can give any short code because new to JS and angular JS

Comment: Updated with more urls, and a bit more details in what you need to do

Comment: Thank you so much for the information, I will try this and will get back to you